# Carousel time(seconds) change with Image change

Tags: flutter, dart

i am using **carousel_slider: ^ 2.2.1**, currently i am getting this data from api,

```
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> data = [
{
  "id": "001",
  "nombre": "Image 1",
  "imagen":
      "https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/2000/1*GqdzzfB_BHorv7V2NV7Jgg.jpeg",
  "time": 20
},
{
  "id": "002",
  "nombre": "Image 2",
  "imagen":
      "https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/2000/1*GqdzzfB_BHorv7V2NV7Jgg.jpeg",
  "time": 5
},
{
  "id": "003",
  "nombre": "Image 3",
  "imagen":
      "https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/2000/1*GqdzzfB_BHorv7V2NV7Jgg.jpeg",
  "time": 15
}
];
```

I have managed to implement the carrousel using an example from the documentation

```
 @override
 void initState() {
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    data.forEach((imageUrl) {
        precacheImage(NetworkImage(imageUrl), context);
      });
     });
    super.initState();
  }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
   appBar: AppBar(title: Text('image slider demo')),
   body: Container(
    child: CarouselSlider.builder(
      itemCount: data.length,
      options: CarouselOptions(
        autoPlay: true,
        aspectRatio: 2.0,
        enlargeCenterPage: true,
      ),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Image.network(data[index].imagen, fit: BoxFit.cover, width: 1000)
          ),
        );
      },
    )
  ),
  );
  }
 }
```

but I'm wondering how can I add the property "time" (seconds). When the carousel moves a new image, I want to change the display duration of the image.
The purpose is to customize the time the image is displayed

Comment: Did you find the answer? I'm looking for the same

Answer (score 0):

add `autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),` in CarouselSlider.